# Right orientation with z up

Tags: vpython

how to make axis x,y,z look like

[image]

```
from visual import *

f = frame()

# Axis
pointer_x = arrow(frame=f, pos=(0,0,0), axis=(40,0,0), shaftwidth=1, color = color.red)
pointer_y = arrow(frame=f, pos=(0,0,0), axis=(0,40,0), shaftwidth=1, color = color.blue)
pointer_z = arrow(frame=f, pos=(0,0,0), axis=(0,0,40), shaftwidth=1, color = color.green)

# Show X,Y,Z labels
label(frame=f,pos=(40,0,0), text='X')
label(frame=f,pos=(0,40,0), text='Y')
label(frame=f,pos=(0,0,40), text='Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

This code solved it, if there is better approach comment it.

```
# Show it like ECEF
f.rotate(angle=radians(-90),axis=(1,0,0),origin=(0,0,0))
f.rotate(angle=radians(180),axis=(0,1,0),origin=(0,0,0))
```